# Scipy inv(A) vs A.I

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm wondering what the difference is between:

```
inv(A)
```

and

```
A.I
```

Both return a Numpy array containing the inverse of the matrix **A**.

`A.I` looks to me like it is accessing a variable from the matrix class which stores the inverse of the matrix; however, this would imply that every time **A** is changed, the inverse of **A** must be recalculated (which doesn't seem logical to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A.I` and `numpy.linalg.inv` are not the same.

`A.I` is a [property](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/dual.py#L36) which calls [matrix.getI](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L817):

```
def getI(self):
    M,N = self.shape
    if M == N:
        from numpy.dual import inv as func
    else:
        from numpy.dual import pinv as func
    return asmatrix(func(self))
```

So `getI` either calls [numpy.dual.inv](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html#numpy-linalg-inv) (the multiplicative inverse of a square matrix) or [numpy.dual.pinv](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) (the Moore-Penrose psuedo-inverse) depending on the shape of the matrix.

If you trace through the definitions (in [dual.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/dual.py#L36)), you'll find that 
`numpy.dual.inv` is `numpy.linalg.inv` and `numpy.dual.pinv` is `numpy.linalg.pinv`.

```
In [69]: s = np.random.random((3,4))

In [70]: t = np.matrix(s)

In [71]: t.I
Out[71]: 
matrix([[ 1.09509751, -0.56685735,  0.51704085],
        [-1.59777153,  0.2777383 ,  1.25579378],
        [ 0.81899054,  0.7594223 , -0.82760378],
        [ 0.02845906,  0.50418885, -0.2091376 ]])

In [72]: np.linalg.inv(t)
...
LinAlgError: Array must be square
```

---

Moreover, `np.linalg.inv` can be applied to numpy arrays (and return a numpy array) as well be applied to numpy matrices. The `matrix.I` property is specific to numpy matrices, and returns another numpy matrix.

```
In [60]: x = np.random.random((3,3))

In [62]: y = np.matrix(x)    

In [64]: type(y.I)
Out[64]: <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>

In [65]: type(np.linalg.inv(x))
Out[65]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

A property, like `A.I` looks syntactically like an attribute, but it actually calls a function (in this case, `A.getI`). So the value of the inverse is not being stored. Every time Python evaluates `A.I`, the function `A.getI()` is called, and the result of the function is returned.

See [Properties: attributes managed by get/set methods](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#property) for more info on properties.

Comment: +1 For the detailed answer, although I am not sure you have stressed enough what seemed to be the OP's main concern: even though `A.I` looks like a stored value, it is being calculated on the fly every time you access it. So for square matrices it is basically syntactic sugar for the exact same operation.

Comment: @Jamie: Thanks, I had forgotten about that part of the question. I've added a bit at the end to (hopefully) rectify that.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer is very helpful and concise!  Read up on attrubutes and the get/set methods.  I don't really understand why finding the inverse of a matrix would make use of the get/set attributes.  It seems logical to just make it, `x.I()`, I suppose `x.I` is more pleasant to look at, but then it means that one has to go remembering whether or not to put brackets or not...

Comment: @user968243: Properties help reduce clutter when you have a getter that takes no arguments (other than self). This improves readability, and [readability counts](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: @user968243: You can to think about the context If you were designing a library for general-purpose programming, one-letter magic properties would probably be seen as horribly unpythonic. But if you're designing a library for numeric computation, translating the mathematical expression A<sup>I</sup> as `numpy` expression A.I makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your versions of Python and `numpy`, `I` (and likewise `T`, etc.) is either a [`@property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), or a custom implementation of the same thing.

If you've never seen this before, the idea is that you can create something that looks like a data attribute (aka "member variable"), but it calls a getter method each time it's accessed.

So, it's not forced to recalculate `A.I` every time you change `A`, but rather every time you access `A.I`.

Of course that might not be any better, depending on your use pattern; it might even be worse. But, just like any other method, there's nothing stopping `numpy` from memoizing (caching results) if it helps.

Under the covers, the getter for `A.I` is `A.getI()`, so these are equivalent, and both are probably equivalent to `inv(A)`. (Having free functions `foo(A)` and methods `A.foo()` that do the same thing is pretty common all over `numpy`.) Except that, as unutbu points out, there's more than one method called `inv`; `A.I` will be equivalent to one of them, but not necessarily the same one you imported directly into the main namespace.